# How do I use a Nagios Perl Plugin?

Tags: cas, nagios

I am trying to monitor my CAS server using a Nagios plugin listed on the JASIG site.

The script runs fine from the command line, so I put it in `/usr/local/nagios/libexec`, made it executable and restarted Nagios.

The command I used is:

```
define command {
    command_name    check_cas
    command_line    check_cas.pl -H cas.baba.org -u "/cas/login" -p 8443 -l abc -a booey -r "Log In Successful"
}
```

From what I can tell, the plugin is not being found:

```
 (Return code of 127 is out of bounds - plugin may be missing)
```

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

The plugins in my configuration either use a variable (`$USER1$=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins`) defined in `/etc/nagios3/resource.cfg` or the complete path of the plugin.

Try to specify the complete path to your plugin, that should help.

Example (Debian nagios plugins)

```
define command{
  command_name  check_ssh
  command_line  /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ssh '$HOSTADDRESS$'
}
```

Example (self defined)

```
define command {
  command_name  check-host-alive
  command_line  $USER1$/check_ping -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5
}
```

Both examples specify the complete path to the plugins. So if you add your path the check will work.

Comment: I have this in my resources.cfg.  Just double-checked.